# What is the "event" part exactly mean in the survcheck function of survival package (R)?

Tags: survival, cox-model

I was doing some project about multi state model,
and I used the code below:

```r
library(survival)
ck <- survcheck(Surv(estart, estop, to) ~ 1, data=mydata, id=id, 
                istate=from)
ck$events
```

Then, the result came like below:

[image]

I can't find the meaning of the last line. (the (any) part)

Does anybody know about that part?